# Python - Subprocess, character limit, split/slice string based on a certain occurrence of a character

Tags: python, string, split, subprocess, slice

`subprocess` in Python has a character limit of 32,000 characters or there abouts. I use subprocess to open an exe and pass it a sequence of commands and am clearing the character limit by leaps and bounds.

My work around is to split the string of commands in two and call `subprocess` twice. I know I can slice a string as follows:

```
commands = '-a 10.162.5.5 399@0000:55:01=0 -a 10.162.5.5 299@0000:55:01=1 -a 10.162.5.5 599@0000:55:01=0 -a 10.162.5.5 699@0000:55:01=0 -a 10.162.5.5 399@0000:55:01=0 -a 10.162.5.5 399@0000:55:01=0 -a 10.162.5.5 499@0000:55:01=1 -a 10.162.5.5 399@0000:55:01=0 -a 10.162.5.5 399@0000:55:01=0 -a 10.162.5.5 399@0000:55:01=0 -a 10.162.5.5 399@0000:55:01=0 -a 10.162.5.5 399@0000:55:01=0 -a 10.162.5.5 799@0000:55:01=34'

print(commands[:len(commands)/2])

print(commands[len(commands)/2:])
```

Unfortunately each command is in a certain format: `-a 10.162.5.5 799@0000:55:01=34`
for example so just a straight split won't work as I could cut a single command in half.

Another idea is to try and split the string at a certain pattern:

```
commands.split(' -')[commands.count('-')/2]
```

Which returns the middle complete command out of the sequence.

Comment: Use a file.  If your command is more than 32000 characters, you really should be doing something else.

What program are you calling?

Comment: Have the commands saved into a new notepad file and then have subprocess read the file? It's a custom in house program and my program  resets a piece of hardware which has a ton of settings.
I go over 32,000 chars for a single board and the device under test can have up to 24 boards.

Comment: Subprocess just calls an external program.  If the program clearly takes command line arguments, but it should be able to read the commands from some sort of text file.
Without knowing the program it is hard to provide an exact solution, but if it needs 600,000+ characters then it is not a command line program!

Comment: `subprocess` itself has no limit. It is upto OS to enforce any limit on the size of the command-line. As @Mark said, you are doing something wrong if you need to type thousands of characters on the command-line. Investigate whether your command accepts options in a file or via its stdin, etc instead.

Answer (score 0):

If all your commands start with a `-a` command switch, you can use this as a quick and dirty way to split up each of your commands:

```
import re
re.findall( "-a[^-]*", commands )
```

The above isn't super ideal though as it will break up commands early if it encounters a hyphen (such as if there are any negative numbers). This is a little more robust way of doing it that will also handle other single letter command line switches (e.g., `-b`, `-c`, etc):

```
import itertools
import re
starts = [match.start() for match in re.finditer( "-[a-z]", commands )]
commandList = [commands[start:end] for start, end in itertools.zip_longest( starts, starts[1:] )]
```

The above is written for Python 3.x. If you're using Python 2.6+ you'll want to replace `zip_longest` with `izip_longest`. Looking at how you're calling your executable, you'll probably want to batch up multiple commands at once to cut down on the overhead of repeatedly calling your executable. You can either concatenate commands repeatedly up to some predetermined length or you can modify your executable to accept some sort of batch file containing your commands (most likely the better option).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

I think concatenating the commands up to a certain length is probably a good direction to take things.
Your other suggestion is a good one too and has been suggested before so it's something else I'll look into.

Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def execute_command(commands):
"""
Execute the commands sent in the 'commands' parameter using the program
specified in the 'program' parameter.
:param commands: A command or sequence of commands
"""
#If the command string is greater than 31,000 characters
if len(commands) > 31000:
    print(len(commands))
    #Find all indices of '-' which represent the start of a new command
    index_start_command = [match.start() for match in re.finditer(re.escape('-'), commands)]
    #split the command string into two, do this by counting the number of times '-' occcurs, half it
    #and return the index of that occurance from the start list.
    commands_one = commands[:index_start_command[commands.count('-')/2]]
    commands_two = commands[index_start_command[commands.count('-')/2]:]
    subprocess.Popen([program, commands_one]).communicate()
    subprocess.Popen([program, commands_two]).communicate()
else:
    subprocess.Popen([program, commands]).communicate()
```

I managed to throw something together which does what I wanted and seems to work. I thought I'd put it up for anyone else who might be banging their head against the wall.